# Declare variable variables using static string and counter variable in a loop

Tags: php, loops, variables, concatenation, variable-variables

How do I create variable variables inside a for loop?

This is the loop:

```
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $aantalZitjesBestellen; $counter ++) {

}
```

Inside this loop, I would like to create a variable $seat for each time it passes but it has to increment like so. first time it passes it should be `$seat1 = $_POST['seat' + $aantalZitjesBestellen]`, next time it passes: `$seat2 = $_POST['seat' + $aantalZitjesBestellen]` and so on.

At the end, it should be:

```
$seat1 = $_POST['seat1'];
$seat2 = $_POST['seat2'];
```

and so on.

The variable and the content of the $_POST should be dynamic.

Comment: Why not make an array?

Comment: Really you should be changing the values in $_POST variables.  Are you doing this because you want to update values on a form you are displaying? If this is the case you might want to consider using javascript for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I would use an array for this unless I'm missing something. Having variables like `$seat1`, `$seat2`, etc tends to have far less utility and be far more cumbersome than using an array.

That being said, use this syntax:

```
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $aantalZitjesBestellen; $counter ++) {
  $key = 'seat' . $counter;
  $$key = $_POST[$key];
}
```

Lastly, PHP has an inbuilt function for extracting array keys into the symbol table: [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). `extract()` has enormous potential security problems if you use it with unfiltered user input (eg `$_POST`) so use with caution.

Comment: And it's strongly discougared to use extract() as it can open security holes in your application.

Answer (score 3):

This will work as well:

```
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $aantalZitjesBestellen; $counter ++) {
    ${'seat' . $counter} = $_POST['seat' . $counter];
}
```

Comment: I prefer this syntax (though I usually use it for properties, not local variables).

Answer (score 2):

(Expanded for clarity - you *may* be able to do a one-liner)

```
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $aantalZitjesBestellen; $counter ++) {
    $varname = 'seat' . $counter;
    $$varname = $POST[$varname];
}
```

**BUT**! You really shouldn't do this. (And if you really must, see [cletus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555057/variable-variables/3555093#3555093) for the built-in PHP way to do it - this is considered bad practice too, though.)

Reconsider your problem and see if arrays might be the solution (I guess it will). This will make both **inspection** (via e.g. `var_dump()`) and **iteration** easier and does not pollute the global variable space.

Comment: This is such bad practice... An array would be so much healthier

Comment: @Pekka Agree (but this answers OP's question). I will elaborate on my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $aantalZitjesBestellen; $counter ++) {
   $name = 'seat' . $counter;
   $$name = $_POST['seat' . $counter];
}
```

It's recommended to use arrays, as you can check them easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) but I don't recommended to do what you are trying to do.