# Variable variables: when useful?

Tags: php, variable-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's an actual use of variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523670)

OK, this question may look a little bit point-whoreish, but I'd really like to know: when are variable variables useful? I haved programmed in PHP for several years, but I've never used them. For me it looks rather funny than useful.

What are some real life examples of variable variables?

*Update:*

I'm really sorry about your votes. The linked 'duplicate' may be really a dupe except one thing: the examples listed there show me **why not to use** variable variables.

Comment: you see a use in the comments of this post : http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/05/31/how-to-use-variable-variables-in-php/

Comment: look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555057/variable-variables

Comment: @Hain, Ayaz, this question IS NOT how to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never. This feature should be banned from the language as well as its other children diseases such as [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), etc.

Comment: I've never met a problem where i found this useful. Arrays are always looks more simple and useful than juggling with variable names without a good reason. Should i think this function is a fail of this language?

Comment: Definitively using variable variables is a sign of a poor design. They are only cool for playing :)

Comment: This would be the first time I've ever downvoted a Col. Shrapnel post. But I disagree with the word "never" - variable variables are useful for templating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it used in some MVC frameworks to initialize variables in the View object.

```
foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value)
{
    // some test would be here so there are no conflicts
    $$key = $value;
}
```

You can then access the the variabels in templates.

**I'm not saying this is a good use though.** Probably a case of poor design.

Comment: Extract is only marginally better. At least you can easily stop it from overwriting existing variables. But since you already have an associative array when you can use extract, you should just use that.

Comment: @delnan: That's my biggest doubt about variable variables: Why create new variables when i can access (array) elements directly?

Comment: @fabrik that's exactly what everyone "dislikes" (to put it mildly) about variable variables: Associative arrays literally provide the same functionality (actually, more - keys are not required to form valid identifiers), but without all the dangers.

Comment: `extract` does the exact same thing as the foreach loop mentioned by @Richard Knop.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful for setting up configuration files dynamically. Check *[PHP and Variable Variables](http://www.untwistedvortex.com/2010/06/06/php-variable-variables/)* for a better idea.

Comment: There is nothing valuable by the first link and second is down.

Comment: I'd rather use .ini files or arrays instead. Variable variables looks unnecessarily complicated to use.

Comment: I would **never even think about** injecting abritary variables from a file into my code... WTF is wrong with an associative array? I consider downvoting, give me a good reason not to.